# Is this a rational function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series, power-series, rational-functions

Is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{2^n-1} \in \mathbb{C}(z)\ ?$$

In a slightly different vein, given a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$, what are some necessary and sufficient conditions for $\sum a_nz^n$ to be in $\mathbb{C}(z)$ with all poles simple?

Comment: By decomposing a rational unction into simple ractions you can get the answer to your question(s).

Comment: Why are there downvotes?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The function
$$ f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{2^n-1} $$
defines a holomorphic function for $|z|<2$, and it satisfies
$$ f(2z) = f(z)+\frac{z}{1-z} $$
for $|z|<1$. Based on this identity, it is easy to prove that $f(z)$ extends to a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$, and the set of poles is $\{2^n:\ n=1,2,\dots\}$. In particular, $f(z)$ does not define a rational function, because its meromorphic extension to $\mathbb{C}$ has infinitely many poles.

Regarding your second question, I recommend the work of Dwork (with which I am not familiar), e.g. (8) in [Alain Robert's article "Des adèles: pourquoi"](http://retro.seals.ch/cntmng?type=pdf&rid=ensmat-001:1974:20::62&subp=hires), and Lemma 9 in [Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/dworks-proof-of-rationality-of-the-zeta-function-over-finite-fields/). See also Remark 2 below.

**Remark 1.** A more direct proof of the above claims follows from the identity
$$ \sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{z}{2^m-z} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^n-1},\qquad |z|<2. $$
Indeed, left hand side defines a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ with pole set $\{2^m:\ m=1,2,\dots\}$.

**Remark 2.** One can give a different, number theoretic proof using [Eisenstein's theorem on algebraic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_theorem) (the proof was [published by Heine](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/download/PPN243919689_0045/log42.pdf) because of Eisenstein's early death). Indeed, the Taylor coefficients of $f(z)$ around the origin are rational, but their denominators $2^n-1$ are not supported on finitely many primes by Fermat's little theorem. (As Gerald Edgar remarked below, this argument proves that $f(z)$ is not even algebraic.)

Comment: So remark 2 is even stronger than the question: this function is not algebraic

Comment: @GeraldEdgar - surely this follows also from the first argument given in this answer? Indeed, any globally defined meromorphic function is either rational or transcendental.

Comment: @LasseRempe-Gillen: I had a similar feeling, but I did not know it from the top of my head, nor did I have the energy to verify it or find the appropriate reference. Thank you!

Comment: @LasseRempe-Gillen : Could you give a reference for this statement "any globally defined meromorphic function is either rational or transcendental". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any globally defined meromorphic function that has a removable singularity (as a function on the Riemann sphere) at $\infty$ is clearly rational. Hence any non-rational meromorphic function in the plane has an essential singularity at infinity, and is transcendental.

Comment: @LasseRempe-Gillen: I think you meant to write 'pole' instead of 'removable singularity'. The key point is that a meromorphic function which has at worst a pole at $\infty$ in fact defines a meromorphic function on the Riemann sphere, and such a function is known to be rational.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E.: a reference for the above statement is O. Forster, *Lectures on Riemann surfaces*, Corollary 2.9.

Comment: @René A pole is precisely a removable singularity, when the function is considered as a function taking values in the Riemann sphere.

Comment: @LasseRempe-Gillen: Oh yes, I see now that you wrote explicitly 'as a function on the Riemann sphere'. My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 26):

Let $F(z)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{2^n-1}$. Then $F(2z)-F(z)=
\frac{z}{1-z}$. Assume that $F(z)$ is rational. Thus $F(z)$ has a
pole at some $z_0\neq 0$, and $F(2z)$ has a pole at $z_0/2$. Let $z_1$ be
a pole of $F(z)$ of maximum absolute value. Let $z_2$ be a pole of
$F(2z)$ of minimum absolute value. Then $z_2\neq z_1$, and both $z_1$
and $z_2$ are poles of $F(2z)-F(z)$, a contradiction.

The "standard" necessary and sufficient condition for a power series
$\sum a_n z^n$ to be a rational function is that the infinite Hankel
matrix $[a_{i+j}]_{i,j\geq 0}$ has finite rank, but I don't know if this
can be applied to the present question. See *Enumerative
Combinatorics*, vol. 1, 2nd ed., Exercise 4.6.

Comment: [the infinite Hankel matrix $[a_{i+j}]_{i,j\geq 0}$ has full rank] didn't you mean _finite rank_ ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E.: thanks, I have corrected this.

Comment: Note that at $n=0$ the denominator $2^n-1$ is zero. Hence I updated the question and my response by omitting the $n=0$ term and changing $\frac{1}{1-z}$ to $\frac{z}{1-z}$.

Comment: @GHfromMO: I have updated my answer correspondingly.

Answer (score 21):

$\sum a_n z^n$ is a rational function iff $a_n$ is a sum of polynomials times exponentials. This is a straightforward corollary of partial fraction decomposition. So, suppose $\frac{1}{2^n - 1}$ can be expressed as such a sum. Taking $n \to \infty$ shows that the largest $r$, in absolute value, such that $r^n$ appears in this sum is $r = \frac{1}{2}$, and moreover (after multiplying both sides by $2^n$) that its polynomial coefficient must be the constant polynomial $1$. That is, the sum must begin

$$\frac{1}{2^n - 1} = \frac{1}{2^n} + \text{smaller terms}.$$

The next largest $r$ such that $r^n$ can apppear in this sum is determined by the asymptotic behavior of $\frac{1}{2^n - 1} - \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2^n(2^n - 1)} \approx \frac{1}{4^n}$, and the same $n \to \infty$ and multiplying by $4^n$ argument as above shows that it must be $r = \frac{1}{4}$ with polynomial coefficient $1$. So the sum must continue

$$\frac{1}{2^n - 1} = \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{4^n} + \text{smaller terms}.$$

But it's clear that in fact we have

$$\frac{1}{2^n - 1} = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{1}{2^{kn}}$$

so this argument never terminates, and it follows that $\frac{1}{2^n - 1}$ cannot be expressed as a finite sum of polynomials times exponentials. This is a less complex-analytic version of the argument that proceeds by showing that the generating function has infinitely many poles.

Answer (score 14):

I would not argue with the irrationality of the function following from the functional equation relating $f(2z)$ to $f(z)$. In fact this function is a particular case of the so-called $q$-logarithm which received a quite special attention. Note that being rational over $\mathbb C(z)$ or over $\mathbb Q(z)$ for a power series with *rational* coefficients is equivalent.

If $f(z)$ where rational then $$f(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2^n-1}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \tau(m)2^{-m}$$ would be a rational number, where $\tau(m)$ denotes the number of divisors of $m$. Erdős proved already in 1948 that this is *not* the case by showing that the base $2$ expansion of the number is not periodic. (This is still a nice exercise in analytic number theory!)

The irrationality of the values of $f(z)$ for rational $z\ne0$ was established by P. Borwein in 1992 using the Padé approximations to the function.

Answer (score 12):

Write $f_0(z)=\sum\frac{z^n}{2^n-1}$ and inductively define $f_k(z)=f_{k-1}(z)-\frac{1}{1-z/2^k}$.  By induction, it is easy to see that $f_k$ is given by the power series $$f_k(z)=\sum\frac{z^n}{2^{kn}-2^{(k-1)n}}.$$

Since each $f_k$ has radius of convergence $2^k$, this shows that $f_0$ does extend to a meromorphic function on all of $\mathbb{C}$.  However, this also shows that the meromorphic extension has poles at $z=2^k$ for all $k>0$, so it cannot be rational.

Answer (score 11):

If I understand well, your question decomposes in two parts the second one being divided in two subparts

Q1) Is $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{2^n-1}$ rational ?

Q2) Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ be a function

Q2.1) How to know if it is rational ?

Q2.2) How to check that it has simple pôles ?

Here are my answers (in part not different from what has been written though, save the last part).

R1) $f$ has radius of convergence $2$ because $\frac{1}{2^n-1}\sim_{n\mapsto +\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}$ and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{2^n}=\frac{2z}{2-z}$$
Computing
$$
f(2z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^nz^n}{2^n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big(1+\frac{1}{2^n-1}\Big) z^n
$$
one gets easily $f(2z)=f(z)+\frac{z}{1-z}$ hence, after having checked that there is no cancellation of the pôle $1$, you get pôles at $\{2^n\}_{n\geq 0}$ which is impossible for a rational fraction.

R2) You use the shift operator. Here there is only one and this question, for several noncommutative series, is closely related to automata theory (see [here](http://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/~duchamp/Publications/Inventiones.pdf), unfortunately in french) and the theory of Sweedler's, duals, see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.0125.pdf). The (one step) shift operator reads

$$\sigma(f)=\frac{f-f(0)}{z}=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_{n+1}z^n\ .$$

Then iterate 
$$f,\sigma(f),\sigma^2(f),\cdots \sigma^n(f)\cdots $$
then either the orbit $\{\sigma^n(f)\}$ is of infinite rank and $f$ is **not rational** or $\{\sigma^n(f)\}$ it is of finite rank and you find a (first) $p$ such that 
$$
\sigma^p(f)=\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\alpha_j\sigma^j(f)
$$ 
the coefficients $\alpha_j$ being complex. Then, you write the **transfer matrix**
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\sigma(f)\\
\sigma^2(f)\\
\vdots\\
\sigma^p(f)
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots &\cdots\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots &\vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 &1\\
\alpha_0 & \cdots & \cdots & \alpha_{p-2} & \alpha_{p-1} 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
f\\
\sigma(f)\\
\vdots\\
\sigma^{p-1}(f)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then the (non-zero) eigenvalues of $T$ (and their multiplicities) give you the (inverses of the) pôles of $f$ and their multiplicities.

**A mini-example** to illustrate the link between the non-zero spectrum of the transfer matrix and the poles.

Let 
$$
f=\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{nz^n}{a^{n+1}},\ a\not=0
$$ 
then the shifts are 
$$
\sigma(f)=\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{(n+1)z^n}{a^{n+2}},\ 
\sigma^2(f)=\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{(n+2)z^n}{a^{n+3}} 
$$
which yields 
$$
\sigma^2(f)=\frac{2}{a}\sigma(f)-\frac{1}{a^2}f
$$
the transfer matrix is then given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\sigma(f)\\
\sigma^2(f)\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1\\
-\frac{1}{a^2} & \frac{2}{a} 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
f\\
\sigma(f)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
its characteristic polynomial is $(X-1/a)^2$.

In fact the fraction was $f=\frac{1}{(z-a)^2}$.

Answer (score 5):

In Prudnikov, Brychkov, Marichev, vol. 1 there is an explicit formula via basic hypergeometric functions. Not rational.

Comment: Could you please point out where (more or less) in the book the formula is?

Comment: Pablo, in my edition of PBM book in english vol. 1 it is P.718, section 5.2.18, f. 13. It is for any $a$ instead of a=2 in your case.